# What's going on in this Newton-Raphson algorithm?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear, algorithm, python

I'm looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1445927/822508) post, over on Mathematics SE. I'll summarize here:

---

A signal with a known velocity, `c` is emitted by some source. We're given the coordinates of four receivers in three dimensions (`[x_i, y_i, z_i]`), the time difference of arrival (`dT`, a.k.a the 'time offset'), and the velocity of the signal, `c`.

The equation for multilateration is of the form:

`sqrt( (x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2 + (z-z_i)^2 ) - c * dT = d_i`

Where `[x,y,z]` are the coordinates of the source, which we want to determine.

**The answerer describes the following solution:**

"To illustrate the method in it's simplest form lets take the 2D problem without the timing offset as an example. We have the equations:"

`sqrt( (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 ) = d_1`

`sqrt( (x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 ) = d_2`

Where `x` and `y` are the unknowns. To solve this using Newton's method, we rephrase it in the form `F(x,y) = 0` for some function `F`. A natural choice to take is `F(x,y) = (f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y))` where:

`f_1(x,y) = sqrt( ( x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 ) - d_1`

`f_2(x,y) = sqrt( ( x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 ) - d_2`

...we can find a new solution by iterating the recurrence:

`J(r_n)(r_n+1 - r_n) = -F(r_n)`

where `J` is the Jacobian matrix and `r_n = (x_n, y_n)`. As opposed to Newton's method in 1D we need to solve a linear equation system `Ax = b` at every step to find the new solution.

**And provides the following code:**

```
(* Desired solution *)
xx = 2.4; yy = 4.2;

(* Constants *)
x1 = 0.5; x2 = 2.4; y1 = 0; y2 = -1.3;
d1 = Sqrt[(xx - x1)^2 + (yy - y1)^2];
d2 = Sqrt[(xx - x2)^2 + (yy - y2)^2];

(* F = 0 function *)
f1[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2] - d1;
f2[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2] - d2;

(* Jacobian matrix *)
J[x_, y_] = {{D[f1[x, y], x], D[f1[x, y], y]}, {D[f2[x, y], x], D[f2[x, y], y]}};

(* Random first guess *)
rn = {-3.7, 8.9};
Do[
  (* Itterate *)
  rn += -Inverse[J[rn[[1]], rn[[2]]]].{f1[rn[[1]], rn[[2]]], f2[rn[[1]], rn[[2]]]};
  Print["Step ",i," Solution = ", rn];
  , {i, 1, 10}];
```

---

I'd like now to expand this to a three-dimensional solution, however I'm not sure precisely how that would differ from the solution offered above. I'd also like to do so in `Python`. I'm familiar with `Numpy` and `SciPy`, but I don't quite follow what's going on in this `Mathematica` code. I feel that everything up to `(* Jacobian Matrix *)` is fairly self-explanatory, but most of what comes after is Latin to me.

I'd like to understand better exactly what steps are being taken here, and how this would expand to a solution in three dimensions, given four observers.

Comment: The last steps are an iteration procedure.  Using braces to indicate a column vector, an exponent of -1 to indicate the matrix inverse and a dot indicate matrix multiplication, the iteration could be written $$ 
\vec{r}_0 = \{ x_0, y_0 \} = \{ -3.7, 8.9 \} \\
\vec{r}_{n+1} = \vec{r}_n - J^{-1}(x_n, y_n) \cdot \{ f_1(x_n,y_n), f_2(x_n,y_n) \} \, ,
$$
where the subscript $n$ runs from 0 to 9, or until the procedure converges.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement your own NR code instead of using `FindRoot`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have several satellites with know positions ri, and would like to calculate your own position: r. Then the time of arrival for the signals from different satellites are different. Therefore I do not understand, why you have only one dT. And the distance to the satellite would be Sqrt[(r-ri).(r-ri)]. The equations would then read: c dTi = Sqrt[(r-ri).(]r-ri)]

Comment: Try **NSolve[{f1[x, y] == 0, f2[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]** The Newton-Raphson's method uses to wander when applied to this kind of problems.